# Objects are being overwritten each time i iterate over the loop

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

Every iteration where I add a new student object, it overwrites the previous objects and contains the same object throughout the list. I tried with linked and array list but continue to have the same problem. If somebody would be kind enough to direct me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Scanner and LinkedList
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedList<Student> studentList = new LinkedList<Student>();
        ArrayList<Student> stdList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        int choice;
        boolean flag = true;
        do {
            Student.showMenu();
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("What is the students last name?");
                String last = keyboard.next();

                System.out.println("What is the students first name?");
                String first = keyboard.next();

                System.out.println("What is the students course code?");
                int courseCode = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("What is the students course grade?");
                String grade = keyboard.next();

                Student st = new Student(last, first, courseCode, grade);
                studentList.add(st);
                stdList.add(st);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                System.out
                        .println("Please enter the students last name you wish to delete.");
                String last = keyboard.next();
                int index = Student.indexOf(studentList, last);
                if (index != -1)
                    studentList.remove(index);
                else
                    System.out.println("Student does not exist.");
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                System.out
                        .println("Please enter the students last name you wish to search.");
                String last = keyboard.next();
                int index = Student.indexOf(studentList, last);
                if (index != -1)
                    studentList.get(index).toString();
                else
                    System.out.println("Student does not exist.");
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            }
            case 5:
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 6:
                Student.displayList(studentList);
                break;
            case 7:
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        } while (flag);

    }




public class Student {
    private static String last;
    private static String first;
    private static int courseCode;
    private static String grade;

public Student(String last, String first, int courseCode, String grade) {
    this.last = last;
    this.first = first;
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
    this.grade = grade;
}

public String getLast() {
    return last;
}

public void setLast(String last) {
    this.last = last;
}

public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}

public int getCourseCode() {
    return courseCode;
}

public void setCourseCode(int courseCode) {
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
}

public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(String grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

public static void showMenu() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the database menu!\n");
    System.out.println("Press 1 to insert a new record");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to delete a record");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to search the database (by last name)");
    System.out.println("Press 4 to print a range in the database");
    System.out.println("Press 5 to find the class average for a course");
    System.out.println("Press 6 to print the list");
    System.out.println("Press 7 to quit");
}

public String toString() {
    String str = " Last name: " + last + " First name: " + first
            + " Course code: " + courseCode + " Course grade: " + grade;
    return str;

}

static int indexOf(LinkedList<Student> list, String last) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Student std : list) {
        if (std.getLast().equals(last))
            return i;
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

static void displayList(LinkedList<Student> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).toString() + " ");

    }
}

static void displayList(ArrayList<Student> stdList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stdList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(stdList.get(i).toString() + " ");

    }

   }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I add a new student object, it overwrites the previous objects and contains the same object throughout the list. " What is this "same object". Is it the first one you entered or the second one?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to list the users. `Student.displayList(studentList)` , infact could you share with us your `Student` class

Comment: That would be good if you provide the complete code, cause that seems to be strange issue.

Comment: @hanumant What i meant by 'same object' is the most recent one. So when i print the list of objects with tostring - it only prints the most 'recent object' for each iteration.

Comment: @hanumant Cant seem to find the problem with displayList... I debugged it as well and it appeared to me that each time an object is added into the list... all previous entries appear to be the same object that i most recently entered..

Comment: @GeorgiyDanielyan, I have ran your code on my machine and everything works fine. As #mushtaq said, please share your complete source code.

Comment: @hanumant I have the student class source code updated at the bottom of the code. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have defined private members of `class Student` as `static`. Any reason to mark them as `static`. Please remove static and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is a rather peculiar problem. My best suggestion would be to change

```
Student st = new Student(last, first, courseCode, grade);
studentList.add(st);
stdList.add(st);
```

to

```
studentList.add(new Student(last, first, courseCode, grade));
stdList.add(new Student(last, first, courseCode, grade));
```

Comment: Eventually you are adding new object to the list in both cases, so I don't think that it would make a difference. The problem would be with the the user is listing the array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your listing code not the adding method, check your iteration code, If you are iterating using a regular `for` which is

> for(int i=0;i

then you must be committing the classic beginners error which is getting the first item for each iteration rather than using the variable assigned such as

> `List.get(0)` rather than `List.get(i)`

I would suggest that you use the **enhanced for** a.k.a the `foreach`for such instances